# How to find if this language is regular or not

Tags: regular-language

I'm currently having trouble with this one:
$$L = \{a^m a^n \mid m, n\text{ is prime}\}$$

I really have no idea. I think it has something to do with Goldbach's conjecture making it impossible to prove, or did I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried to apply the Pumping Lemma?

Comment: @BLAZE : I changed your "vertical bar" to \mid, which has proper spacing in this context and is standard.

Comment: @Michael Looks better, thanks, I will have to remember that syntax.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Prove that the language $L \cap (a^2)^*a$ is not regular.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the hint. If I understand correctly, I can assume that L is regular then L∩(a2)∗a is also regular. So if i can find a way to find that L∩(a2)∗a is not regular then we have a contradiction and I can say L is not regular?

Comment: Exactly...  And you can use the fact that the only even prime is $2$.

Comment: You are welcome.